# Create many wars with defferent profiles by gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have java project build by gradle. I created 4 profiles. Each profile supports setting of different database(postgresql, h2, mysql, mssql). Postgresql profile is default.
After one command `gradle clean build`  I want to get 4 war files, each build in different profile.
How can I achieve it?

I can create bash script and run build command four time(gradle clean build -Pdb=postgresql, gradle clean build -Pdb=h2, ...) and after each build copy result war file but I don't want use this solution.

Already I have tried to create war, example for postgresql like this:

```
task createPostgresWar(type: War) {
        baseName = 'projectName_postgres'
        destinationDir = file("../build/libs")
    }
```

and it works fine but before every this type of task I want also rebuild project with correct profile.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have four separate tasks defined for creating wars, like `createPostgreWar`, `createH2War` etc, you can add these tasks as dependencies to the build task as follows:

```
build.dependsOn createPostgresWar, createH2War, <other war tasks>
```

Running `gradle build` will now trigger all these war tasks.

Comment: Yes I try this but this solution create four exactly the same war files. The build also have to generate some configuration files for each profile

Comment: You should be able to customize each war task using the options available. Take a look at [this link](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html). Specifically, you might be interested in the `includes` section for customizing the war contents.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar to create several jars in one build, but it should be the same for wars. Put your config files in different dirs like this:

common configs:

```
/src/META-INF/...
```

Special configs for each db:

```
/src/postgresql/META-INF/...
/src/h2/META-INF/...
```

Now the script below will build four different jars. Each of the created jars will contain the config files from **/src/META-INF/** plus these from the appropriate **/src/xxx/META-INF/**. You'll probably have to change the task type to War.

```
def customJar(String db) {
    task(db, type: Jar) {

        baseName = 'projectName'
        appendix = db
        destinationDir = file("../build/libs")

        from('src')
        from("src/${db}")

        def commonDir = new File(projectDir.absolutePath + "/src/META-INF/")
        def concreteDir = new File(projectDir.absolutePath + "/src/${db}/META-INF/")
        exclude {
            (!new File(concreteDir, it.file.name).absolutePath.equals(it.file.absolutePath)
                    && new File(concreteDir, it.file.name).isFile()
                    || !it.file.absolutePath.startsWith(concreteDir.absolutePath)
                    && !it.file.absolutePath.startsWith(commonDir.absolutePath))
        }
    }
}

artifacts {
    archives customJar("postgresql"),
            customJar("h2"),
            customJar("mysql"),
            customJar("mssql")
}
```